# Angularjs routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning Angularjs and having problem with routing. I write up a very simple slim demo example which uses out of the box MVC5.  The home page display fine but when I click on the About link it doesn't show the About page and AboutController break point is not hit.  And got the following error in Console
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: templates/indexView.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found).

If I swap the two route, then my About page is displayed but got the error when clicking Home link so I am sure the html can be loaded.  What do I need to do in order to get the routing to work?

Below is the index.cshtml

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.InitModule = "homeIndex";
}
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/home-index.js"></script>
}

<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

Below is the About.cshtml

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Page";
    ViewBag.InitModule = "homeIndex";
}
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/home-index.js"></script>
}

<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

below is the home-index.js

```js
// home-index.js
var module = angular.module("homeIndex", ["ngRoute"]);

var angularFormsApp = angular.module('homeIndex', ["ngRoute"]);

angularFormsApp.config(["$routeProvider", 
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "templates/indexView.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            })
            .when("/About", {
                templateUrl: "templates/aboutView.html",
                controller: "AboutController"
            });
    }]);


angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
    ["$scope", 
    function ($scope) {
        var x = 1;

    }]);


angularFormsApp.controller("AboutController",
    ["$scope",
    function ($scope) {
        var x = 1;

    }]);
```

The var x=1 has no meaning just for me to set a break point.

Below is indexView.html

```html
<h3>Arrived at Index Page</h3>
```

aboutView.html

```html
<h3>About Page</h3>
```

I also have the below in the _Layout.cshtml html tag to hook in angular
 data-ng-app="@ViewBag.InitModule"

Comment: Hi

Angular and MVC are both trying to handle the routing which can lead to some unexpected behaviour!

Do you actually have the
 "templates/indexView.html" and "templates/aboutView.html" files?

Comment: @OliverMoolman yes. the 2 htmls files are in the solution under templates folder

Comment: why use angular routing in asp mvc project? Use asp mvc routing and angular for front end, calling asp. net mvc controller is easy, let me know if you need example
Ps I'm pretty sure asp controller grabs request first, looks for about controller and index action in it, you probably dont have it, that's why you get 404 page not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that MVC is handling the routing that you expect to be handled by Angular.

Have a look at this question for some more information about having Both AngularJS and MVC in the same project:
[Should I be using both AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305838/should-i-be-using-both-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc)

Here is a nice guide to getting started using the two together, it specifically touches on the routing as well:
[Getting started with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par)

I hope that helps, please let us know if you need more information, or if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for the references.  It helps me understand how MVC and Angular work together